# loop through image folder and return the next 3 images each time

Tags: php

I currently have a folder of images I'm trying to loop through with an AJAX call and I want to just return 3 at a time until the end, then start over from the beginning.

I'm having issues coming up with the logic with the portion of starting from the beginning if the end is reached.

This is currently what I have.

```
$images = glob("images/*.jpg");

// sort images by file time
usort($images, function($a, $b) {
     return filemtime($a) < filemtime($b);
});

$images = array_slice($images, $start_pos, 3);
```

To slice the images into groups of 3 `$start_pos` would be at 0, then after the first call, go up to 3 to return images 4,5,6. But currently, if I don't have more than 3 images, setting `$start_pos` of 3 would return nothing, instead of starting over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (count($images) > 3) {
    $start_pos += 3;
}
$images = array_slice($images, $start_pos, 3);
```

Comment: pass the value of start_pos back and forth with your AJAX call to retain the number if that is important.

Answer (score 0):

Loop circularly using modulus.

```
$selectedImages=array();
$imageNum=0;
for($i=$start_pos%count($images);$imageNum<3;i=(i+1)%count($images),$imageNum++)
{
    $selectedImages[$imageNum]=$images[$i]
}
```